# Rank in subquery

Tags: mysql, dense-rank

I'm looking to report the best seller by total sales price using the table below:
Sales table:

seller_id   |  quantity  |  price

| 1     | 2        | 2000  |

| 1       | 1        | 800   |

| 2       | 1        | 800   |

| 3        2        | 2800  |

The result need to be 1 & 3 (a table with 1 column "seller_id")since both sellers with id 1 and 3 sold products with the most total price of 2800

I tried to write a query using rank.. in a subquery, I will have something like:

SELECT
sum(price), rank() over (order by price desc )
FROM
sales
group by seller_id

Then, I need to select the sum(price) with rank=1, but I don't know how to write that..
Then, outside of the subquery, I want to select just the seller_id.
How do we do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RANKING function for retrieving seller_id based on highest price. RANK() function serialize the position with a GAP. If two values in same position then third value position after this to value will 3 not 2.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT t.seller_id, t.total_price
FROM (SELECT seller_id, SUM(price) total_price
      , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC) rank_price
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY seller_id) t
WHERE t.rank_price = 1
```

DENSE_RANK() function serialize the position without a GAP. If top 5 price needed in future then it'll better.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT t.seller_id, t.total_price
FROM (SELECT seller_id, SUM(price) total_price
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(price) DESC) rank_price
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY seller_id) t
WHERE t.rank_price = 1
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90c756fa6d3ab25914721cfe40df5e9a